# What kind of worship does God look for, for Salvation?

Tags: soteriology, christian-living, worship

Through Gods word the bible, we are given commandments of what we shouldn't do and what we need to do in order to attain salvation.

That last part is really what I'm focusing on. **What does the New Testament tell us about what we need to do to be in accordance with God**?

How much of the Old Testament still applies?

Sources from anywhere are acceptable, however I am primarily looking for sources from the scriptures. Please include scriptures that come to mind to support your ideas!

For instance I am looking for something along these lines:

Jesus said we need to be doing X or displaying X qualities. Here is the scripture where he said that (Insert scripture here).

---

I searched for similar questions and didn't find any that articulated what I'm looking for. If this question has been asked, I apologize and will delete this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some scriptures that will help:

1 Corinthians 15:1-2  KJV

> Moreover, brethren, I declare unto you the gospel which I preached unto you, which also ye have received, and wherein ye stand; By which also ye are saved, if ye keep in memory what I preached unto you, unless ye have believed in vain.

1 Timothy 4:14-16  KJV

> Neglect not the gift that is in thee, which was given thee by prophecy, with the laying on of the hands of the presbytery. Meditate upon these things; give thyself wholly to them; that thy profiting may appear to all.  Take heed unto thyself, and unto the doctrine; continue in them: for in doing this thou shalt both save thyself, and them that hear thee.

Ezekiel 33:12-19  KJV

> Therefore, thou son of man, say unto the children of thy people, The righteousness of the righteous shall not deliver him in the day of his transgression: as for the wickedness of the wicked, he shall not fall thereby in the day that he turneth from his wickedness; neither shall the righteous be able to live for his [righteousness] in the day that he sinneth. When I shall say to the righteous, [that] he shall surely live; if he trust to his own righteousness, and commit iniquity, all his righteousnesses shall not be remembered; but for his iniquity that he hath committed, he shall die for it. Again, when I say unto the wicked, Thou shalt surely die; if he turn from his sin, and do that which is lawful and right;  [If] the wicked restore the pledge, give again that he had robbed, walk in the statutes of life, without committing iniquity; he shall surely live, he shall not die. None of his sins that he hath committed shall be mentioned unto him: he hath done that which is lawful and right; he shall surely live. Yet the children of thy people say, The way of the Lord is not equal: but as for them, their way is not equal. When the righteous turneth from his righteousness, and committeth iniquity, he shall even die thereby. But if the wicked turn from his wickedness, and do that which is lawful and right, he shall live thereby.

This what I use:

John 15:6

> If a man abide not in me, he is cast forth as a branch, and is withered; and men gather them, and cast [them] into the fire, and they are burned.

And in order to Abide in Christ I remind myself of what Salvation really is; and how I gained it in the first 
place.

```
1.  By first acknowledging my sin, to that end I remember what Jesus said about that in the Lord's prayer.

   a. Forgive us our debts as we forgive our debtors.

        1. So to start I ask god to forgive anyone who has irked me that day and forgive them in my heart. that
         also makes me sleep better at night.

    2.  Only after I have forgiven them do I ask God to forgive me for what I have done wrong.

    3.  I have to  make a concentrated effort each day to act exactly the way Jesus did.

    a. By that I mean try to love others as Jesus did and that means that I just do not expect them to be or do as
    I think they should but accept them as if had.

    b. It seems to me that to be like Jesus means that I should reject the things which are ungodly and support 
    those things which are.     

     c. This is the big one, I need to do all I can to exhibit Jesus to the world and People around me, and to
     honor God in all my actions.
```

As far as just what Scriptures will help you to live a life pleasing to God I can only say all of them, and in order to do that I have to study my Bible every day, and ask the Holy Spirit to give me understanding.

Oh and by the way Jesus said that not even a accent mark of the Scripture would eve pass away, so all of the Old Testament is still in effect only that Jesus fulfilled all of the law.

Comment: This is a pretty thorough answer instilled with wisdom. I will answer myself when I have some time on my hands again. Thank you for your perspective :)

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question about salvation, is super-simple.
We do nothing to receive the Gift of Salvation.
We just **acknowledge** our sinful nature, which opens the way for us to **believe** that what Christ has done on the cross is enough to save us from eternal separation from God (refer to John 3:16 and John 14:6 as the super-abridged version of this truth).

The next question is, what then shall I do after I'm saved? Only at this point the concept of worship, bible-doctrines, fruits of the spirit, missionary, serving/giving-sacrificially start to make sense.

Comment: Jesus said that not everybody saying "Lord Lord" will be saved. Being chosen to be saved has requirements such as those in the second half of your answer. Jesus's sacrifice opened the way to salvation, but it takes action on our part to attain it. Thank for your answer

Comment: In John 3:16, the only requirement is to believe. In Matthew 7:21 the Lord said that not everyone who says "Lord, Lord" will *enter the kingdom of heaven*, not *saved*.

If you do more reading in the Scriptures about "entering the kingdom of heaven", you would see that it is not the same as the Gift of Salvation, which is by definition something that we receive, not something that we have to work towards.

Answer (score 0):

Praise The Lord

There is **NOTHING** one can do to attain salvation. It is absolutely the grace of God that salvation is given to us.

What kind of worship? A genuine heart always The Bible and the gospels as your standard for your personal position with God.

Jesus Himself mentioned the old testament many times, the old testament is all about the law and the new testament is Grace. The last word of the old testament and the beginnings of the new testament ought to encourage you.

Answer (score 0):

One of the greatest gifts that God gave mankind was giving his son to die, so that everyone would have a chance to live. This act shows us how much God loves mankind. It shows us qualities about him such as forgiveness, patience, mercy, justice, and greatest of all love.

In order to take advantage of that gift we need to show that we appreciate it with our actions. We need to constantly ask ourselves "Does the way I live seem to be in accordance with Gods laws"? This will keep us from forming bad habits and keep us on the road to salvation.

How can we know God's laws if we don't read the bible diligently? Seeking God's forgiveness without knowing his commandments is like trying to get somewhere with a map that you don't know how to use. With frequent bible reading we get a sense of what God requires of us.

By reading God's inspired word in the scriptures you see that there is more to pleasing God than just showing up for Church/service on Sundays. At [**James 2:24&26**](http://www.jw.org/en/publications/bible/nwt/books/james/2/#v59002024) Jesus say's this:

> 24 "You see that a man is to be declared righteous by works and not by faith alone." 26 "Indeed, just as the body without spirit is dead, so also faith without works is dead."

The bible also tells us that we need to follow **all** the things Jesus taught us as best as possible. Not everyone blending into the flock crying "Lord, Lord" will be saved. [**Matthew 7:21&26**](http://www.jw.org/en/publications/bible/nwt/books/matthew/7/#v40007021):

> “Not everyone saying to me, ‘Lord, Lord,’ will enter into the Kingdom of the heavens, but only the one doing the will of my Father who is in the heavens will." 26 "Furthermore, everyone hearing these sayings of mine and not doing them will be like a foolish man who built his house on the sand."

Jesus gave us a very powerful illustration of how we will recognize true worship of God. [**Matthew 7:16-17&20**](http://www.jw.org/en/publications/bible/nwt/books/matthew/7/#v40007016)

> "By their fruits you will recognize them. Never do people gather grapes from thorns or figs from thistles, do they? 17  Likewise, every good tree produces fine fruit, but every rotten tree produces worthless fruit." 20 "Really, then, by their fruits you will recognize those men"

So we are able to draw from this that we need to be displaying certain actions in order to be considered fit for salvation. What does the bible tell us we need to be doing?

When the pharisees tested Jesus they asked "Teacher, what is the greatest commandment in the law". [**Matthew 22:37**](http://www.jw.org/en/publications/bible/nwt/books/matthew/22/#v40022037) Jesus said:

> “You must **love** Jehovah your God with your whole heart and with your whole soul and with your whole mind."

After he answered them they asked what the second greatest commandment was. Jesus told them that it was to "**Love** your neighbor as yourself". The reason behind Jesus's words is in verse 40 of that chapter:

> "On these two commandments the whole Law hangs, and the Prophets.”

Then **Love** is what should be the motive behind all our actions. Like God our love for others should motivate us to **forgive**, **be patient**, and strive to show **compassion** for others helping those in need.

Our love and compassion helps us to accomplish a very important work. **Preaching God's word to all the nations**. We where given a commandment from Jesus to do this. [**Matthew 28:19-20**](http://www.jw.org/en/publications/bible/nwt/books/matthew/28/#v40028019):

> "Go, therefore, and **make disciples** of people of all the nations, **baptizing** them in the name of the Father and of the Son and of the holy spirit, **teaching** them to observe all the things I have commanded you."

Why do we minister, teach and baptize? [**John 17:3**](http://www.jw.org/en/publications/bible/nwt/books/john/17/#v43017003) answers this nicely:

> "This means everlasting life, their coming to know you, the only true God, and the one whom you sent, Jesus Christ."

Not only does knowledge mean everlasting life, it also means you have helped save that person from death! The ministry work should be our first and foremost concern as Christians.  Jesus gave us a warning about seeking valuable things in this world. [**Matthew 6:24**](http://www.jw.org/en/publications/bible/nwt/books/matthew/6/#v40006033):

> “No one can slave for two masters; for either he will hate the one and love the other, or he will stick to the one and despise the other. **You cannot slave for God and for Riches**."

Another way to look at this is to ask yourself "how much time am I spending on godly pursuits vs. worldly gains?". Do we work to pay the bills and provide for our family or do we work to get nice things or that is "Treasures in this world"?

Part of being a Christian is sharing in preaching work Jesus left for us to finish.

A topic I will touch just a little more on is **forgiveness**. If we do not display this quality of God why then would he give it to us? [**Matthew 6:14-15**](http://www.jw.org/en/publications/bible/nwt/books/matthew/6/#v40006014):

> “For if you forgive men their trespasses, your heavenly Father will also forgive you;  whereas if you do not forgive men their trespasses, neither will your Father forgive your trespasses."

There are other things that we need to be doing as Christians. Pray to God regularly and properly, give to God your material things, observe the lords evening meal, displaying the fruit of the holy spirit, and having faith in both God and Jesus's sacrifice.

If we keep seeking God and put faith in him then our chances of obtaining his protection and salvation are very good. [John 3:36](http://www.jw.org/en/publications/bible/nwt/books/john/3/#v43003036):

> "The one who exercises faith in the Son has everlasting life; the one who disobeys the Son will not see life, but the wrath of God remains upon him."

I exhort all of you to keep on loving, learning, ministering, and exercising faith in order to stay awake spiritually. May God bless your efforts.